# Integrating Hudson with UCM Clearcase on windows machine

Tags: hudson, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I've installed Hudson on my windows machine and trying to integrate it with UCM Clearcase (the repository we are using).
There are no help docs available on Hudson wiki to explain how to do that.

- I select `New Job --> Project Name`
- I give as `Test --> select Build a free style software project --> click Ok`
- --> This leads me to Configure Project screen
- --> Under `Source Code management` I select `UCM Clearcase`
- --> I give a dynamic view name I've already created and the name of the integration stream (in stream selector)
- --> Under `Advanced options` I select "`Use UCM dynamic view`" and give view root as `M:\` and in "`Windows dynamic view storage directory`" I give `\\Hostname\CC_Views\MyTestView.vws`.

Now I run the project to check if the fetch in working properly or not and I get this error:

```
[advcm3_LAC_FN38_Test] $ cleartool pwv -root M:\advcm3_LAC_FN38_Test
[workspace] $ cleartool startview advcm3_LAC_FN38_Test 
[advcm3_LAC_FN38_Test] $ cleartool setcs -tag advcm3_LAC_FN38_Test -stream
cleartool: Warning: Config spec OK, but unable to tell view server to load.
cleartool: Warning: View server should be restarted.
cleartool: Error: Unable to change configuration specification: Permission denied.
FATAL: UCM ClearCase failed. exit code=1
java.io.IOException: cleartool did not return the expected exit code. Command line="setcs -tag advcm3_LAC_FN38_Test -stream", actual exit code=1
 at hudson.plugins.clearcase.HudsonClearToolLauncher.run(HudsonClearToolLauncher.java:107)
 at hudson.plugins.clearcase.HudsonClearToolLauncher.run(HudsonClearToolLauncher.java:70)
 at hudson.plugins.clearcase.ClearToolDynamicUCM.setcs(ClearToolDynamicUCM.java:81)
 at hudson.plugins.clearcase.ClearToolDynamicUCM.syncronizeViewWithStream(ClearToolDynamicUCM.java:66)
 at hudson.plugins.clearcase.action.UcmDynamicCheckoutAction.checkout(UcmDynamicCheckoutAction.java:99)
 at hudson.plugins.clearcase.AbstractClearCaseScm.checkout(AbstractClearCaseScm.java:398)
 at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1038)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:479)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:411)
 at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1257)
 at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:129)
```

> Nothing has been fetched into `C:\Hudson\jobs\Test\workspace`.

Can someone please guide me in this?

Thanks,
Umang

Answer (score 0):

This is usually symptomatic of an ACL issue.

You need to:

- make sure what user are actually running the Hudson Jobs (and with what `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` environment value)
- check the view protection

```
    cd m:\advcm3_LAC_FN38_Test
    cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview
```

If the user differ, you need to reprotect the view

```
fix_prot -force -r -chown rightUser -chgrp rightGroup -chmod 775 \\Hostname\CC_Views\MyTestView.vws.
fix_prot -force -root -chown rightUser -chgrp rightGroup \\Hostname\CC_Views\MyTestView.vws.
```

`fix_prot` is in `c:/Program Files/rational/clearcase/etc/utils` for CC7.0 or  less, or `c:/Program Files/IBM/RationalSDLC/clearcase/etc/utils` for CC7.1 or more.

Note: it is strange that a view called `advcm3_LAC_FN38_Test` has an associated view storage called `MyTestView.vws`.

I would have rather expected a `\\Hostname\CC_Views\advcm3_LAC_FN38_Test.vws`.

Comment: Thanks VonC for the reply. Can this issue be because my Hudson job is running under anonymous user while to talk with CC I must be a CC user?

Comment: @Umang: I would certainly try to make sure the Hudson job runs with an appropriate user rather than the anonymous one.