# Getting error while updating the view

Tags: clearcase

I am getting below error while updating the view.

Problems were encountered while retrieving view synchronization and data.

```
Clearcase CM server error: Unable to access "vob name" : unknown error in vob
Clearcase CM server error: Error 2 config spec load rule problems encountered
```

How to troubleshoot that error message?

Comment: Have you checked if your VOB accessible? Try (from command-line: cleartool lsvob "vob name" or cleartool desc vob:"vob name"

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the logs (both locally or on the server) to know more.
It used to be [`cleartool getlog`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_getlog.htm) (ClearCase 7.x, [even for CC 8.x](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/r_intro_serverprocs_logs.htm?lang=en))

```
cleartool: Error: Checkout is currently disabled for element "element_name".
Its config spec rule information is currently unavailable due to either an aborted update or an update in progress
```

That is similar to an older CC (7.0.x) described [in this technote](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21206362):

> ### Possible cause for symptom 1:
>
> If an update, rebase or deliver operation is not currently in progress for the view in question, the error can often be attributed to the view being out of sync with the stream.

Try:

```
cd /path/to/snapshot/view
cleartool setcs -stream
```

### Possible cause for symptom 2:

> Hijacked nocheckout means that the version hijacked in the view is no longer the version the config spec selects from the VOB.

1. Rename the hijacked file and update the view.
2. Check out the version from which the file was hijacked.
3. Copy the hijacked file over the checked-out version.
4. Merge from the current version to the checked-out version.
5. The version can now be checked in.

> ### Possible cause for symptom 3:
>
> Per the error message explanation noted above, the problem may be caused by an issue with the view's config spec or an aborted or incomplete view update.

Try:

```
cd /path/to/snapshot/view
cleartool setcs -current
```

---

(original answer)

It can be a right issue, [as illustrated by this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013991814#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013992278).

> Check group permissions on user and on those two VOBs.
> Do you rely on the `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` environment variable?
> If so, check the value of the user performing the update.

Compare the rights of the vob with the ones for your current snapshot view that you are trying to update:

```
cd /path/to/snapshot/view
cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview
```

If the `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` is not set properly, it is easier to:

- set it to the right group (ie the primary group of the vob, or one of the secondary groups)
- delete and recreate your view.
  (if you do not want to delete/recreate your view, [you can fix_prot it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3306064/6309))

Comment: The issue is not with CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP. Multiple users are getting diffenent errors:Problems performing checkout.


ClearCase CM Server: Error: Checkout is currently disabled for element "path" 
An update appears to have been aborted or errors were 
encountered during an update.  An update must be performed 
on the element to enable a checkout.                                           ClearCase CM Server: Error: Checkout is currently disabled for element "path". 
Its config spec rule information is currently unavailable 
due to either an aborted update or an update in progress.

Comment: @sakshi What version of ClearCase are you using?

Comment: @sakshi Is is an UCM view (attached to a stream) or a base CC view?

Comment: @sakshi try at least the option n° 3: `cd /path/to/snapshot/view && 
cleartool setcs -current`