# Database timed-out issue in Clearcase UCM

Tags: clearcase-ucm

I am facing Database timed-out issue while creating a view and/or rebasing a stream on vobs

```
ERROR -> cleartool: Error: Database timed out -- aborting transaction: "\TP".
ERROR -> cleartool: Error: Unable to generate config spec for stream "stream name".
```

I am using CCRC to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database timed out error is resolved after following this http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21133944

> - Lock the VOB (if you receive errors from the lock command, proceed to step 2.)
> - Unmount the VOB
> - Kill any lingering VOB processes on the server using the albd_list utility.
>     Note: Review technote 1148639 for more details on albd_list and its usage.
>     Should some ClearCase processes still exist that are accessing the transaction files and preventing you from deleting them, you must completely - stop ClearCase on the server to end those processes.
> - Move the vista.tjf, vista.tcf, vista.taf files out of the VOB db directory
>     Refer to technote 1149322 About ClearCase database vista.* files for further information about these files.
> - Remount the VOB
>
> The files will be recreated and the VOB will be functional
>
> Note: If the files are not recreated, stop and restart ClearCase services on the host.

Answer (score 1):

CCRC possibly means CC8.0.X+, but you would still need to access logs (that was [`cleartool getlog` in previous CC versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34085430/6309), since [you mentioned before using CC 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34083560/getting-error-while-updating-the-view#comment55927577_34085430)), in order to know more about that error message.

A "`Database timed out -- aborting transaction`" usually is followed on the logs by the actual root cause (like, for instance, `db_VISTA database error -926 - problem in shared memory lock manager`)

In the [OP's case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34197993/6309), it was (from [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21133944)), a corrupt transaction file.

```
Error: db_VISTA error -925
```