# Access Error On UCM project

Tags: clearcase-ucm

I am getting the below error while accessing the project :

```
Unable to create new element for " path"
ccweb: Error: Config spec indicates that checkouts are not allowed for element "path"
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided you did solve [your Database timed-out issue in Clearcase UCM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34151032/6309), that error message is not surprising.

The [technote "About non-UCM and UCM views"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21237056) mentions:

> **Working in a UCM view will return an error if accessing a VOB or component that is not associated with its project**:

```
cleartool: Error: Config spec indicates that checkouts are not allowed for element "<some element>".
```

> 1. Views can only be used to work on a single stream, under a specific project and in modifiable components that are associated with that project.
> 2. New versions created by a checkin are catalogued in an activity
> 3. Metadata is applied automatically to checked in versions
> 4. Operations, such as cleartool mkactivity, are recorded at the project level

If you are trying to add to source control a file in a path which is not part of a writable UCM component declared on the stream which is referenced by your UCM views, you would get that message.