# Not able to Set View in Base clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I am not able to set view on the server even though I have re-mounted the file system , getting below error :

```
$ cleartool setview view_name
cleartool: Error: Timed out trying to start view_server for view PATH
cleartool: Error: See view server error log and/or look for view_server problem on host Hostname
cleartool: Error: Couldn't set view tag tagename: error detected by ClearCase subsystem
```

Comment: What ClearCase version are you using? What OS is your ClearCase client running on? What OS is the ClearCase server running on?

Answer (score 0):

First, try to avoid [*`enter code here`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setview.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-66): [it spawns a subshell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309) which is tricky for your current session and environment variables.

Then, check if the issue us the same when you simply try to start that dynamic view:

```
cleartool start <aDynamicViewName>
```

Typically, looking at the logs might tell you more about the issue:

```
cleartool getlog error *
cleartool getlog -host <clearcaseServer> view
```

(Remember: [you had database timeout before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34197993/6309))