# Checkout file is not working in Eclipse with Clearcase plugin

Tags: eclipse, clearcase

I am trying to checkout a file in Eclipse with Clearcase, not able to do it. I am inside the view, .project and .classpath is available within the project.

When we click on the checkout icon in the eclipse, it was saying "checking out the elements" but it is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Eclipse logs](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F): depending on the version of Eclipse (`workspace/.metadata/.log` or `eclipse/configuration/*.log`), the exact version of the Eclipse ClearCase plugin and the OS you are using, you might find some clues in said log.

Also, check if the same checkout works in command line:

```
cd C:\path\to\my\project
cleartool ls
cleartool co -nc myFile
```

Comment: Hi, I am using eclipse 4.3 version and Clearcase SCM Adapter

Comment: I am using eclipse 4.3 version and Clearcase SCM Adapter, OS: Unix, through command line checkout is happening. i got the log in the below path: eclipse-4.3/eclipse/configuration/1476943964905.log but not explaining about "checkout". any other log which explains about check out log?

Comment: @user1234567 yes: the logs from ClearCase itself (like `cleartool getlog -host <clearcaseServer> view`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34537160/6309)

Comment: @user1234567 And check the result of a `cleartool ls`: it should display the associated status for that file.

Comment: @user1234567 Also, what version of ClearCase are you using?